# What is wrong with this syntax?

Tags: jquery, syntax

```
$(".questionsList").toggle(function() { 
    if (e.target.nodeName == 'h1') {
        return;
    } else {       
        $('#slider').animate({ left: '375' }, 500);
        },  function() {
            $('#slider').animate({ left: '0'}, 500);
    } 
});
```

Comment: Fixed indentation and you will see your problem

Comment: this is why we format our code better

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you needed was <strike>correct</strike> a sane looking indentation to find the problem :)

```
$(".questionsList").toggle(function() { 
        if(e.target.nodeName == 'h1') {
            return;
        } else {       
            $('#slider').animate({ left: '375' }, 500);
        }
    }, // <-- you're missing this flower bracket
    function() {
        $('#slider').animate({ left: '0'}, 500);
    }); // <-- you have an extra flower bracket here
```

Comment: flower bracket!? never heard it called that before. AKA curly bracket/braces?

Comment: LMAO flower bracket! Hahahaha

Comment: Marko's comment pretty much says why I call it that way :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need an additional `}` after your `} else {..}` statement, and remove a `}` before `});` (you have two).

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".questionsList").toggle(function() { 
                  if(e.target.nodeName == 'h1') {
                      return;
                  }  
             else {       
                  $('#slider').animate({ left: '375' }, 500);
                }},  function() {
                    $('#slider').animate({ left: '0'}, 500);
                }

                );
```